# Angular Paginator Intl Several Options

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

after reading 
[How to use MatPaginatorIntl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46869616/how-to-use-matpaginatorintl)
I have successfully managed to adapt a MatPaginatorIntl to my needs.

However, I would like to know how to use different MatPaginatorIntl for different sorts of table in my Angular App?

I have added to my AppModule.ts
`providers: [{ provide: MatPaginatorIntl, useClass: MatPaginatorIntlCro}],`

But just adding another MatPaginatorIntl as a Provider won't change my issue because I can only provide one.

So I probably have to find a way to use different providers of MatPaginatorIntl for differen tables. Does anyone have an idea how to approach this?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I donno if I had understood your question properly. As you have added in the providers of `app.module.ts`, it is applied across all the components. Try to put these providers in the nearest/enclosing module of the component in which you are using the paginator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I donno if I had understood your question properly. As you have added in the providers of `app.module.ts`, it is applied across all the components.

Try to put these providers in the nearest/enclosing module of the `component` in which you are using the `paginator`.