# how should I change Material Table titles using transloco i18n(internationalization) liabrary for pagination and page range, next , previous buttons?

Tags: angular, angular-material, transloco

want to show titles using i18n
    
[Above is the image for showing titles 'items per page'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXdPB.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ***MatPaginatorIntl*** interface and extend it. Here is an example of Serbian labels

```
export function getSerbianPaginatorIntl() {
  const paginatorIntl = new MatPaginatorIntl();

  paginatorIntl.itemsPerPageLabel = 'Stavki po strani:';
  paginatorIntl.nextPageLabel = 'Sledeca strana';
  paginatorIntl.previousPageLabel = 'Prethodna strana';
  paginatorIntl.getRangeLabel = serbianRangeLabel;

  return paginatorIntl;
}
```

full example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5mgfxh-cwgmym?file=app%2Fdutch-paginator-intl.ts

Comment: thanks for the answer but I want to manage multiple languages so I manage to do it with transloco using angular service.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53877024/7733592 
this helps me to do for multiple langs

Answer (score 0):

First, create a custom `MatPaginatorIntl` that uses `Transloco` for translation.

```
import { MatPaginatorIntl } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { TranslocoService } from '@ngneat/transloco';

export class TranslocoPaginatorIntl extends MatPaginatorIntl {
  constructor(private _translocoService: TranslocoService) {
    super();

    this._translocoService.selectTranslateObject('table').subscribe((translation) => {
      this.itemsPerPageLabel = translation.itemsPerPage;
      this.nextPageLabel = translation.nextPage;
      this.previousPageLabel = translation.previousPage;
      this.firstPageLabel = translation.firstPage;
      this.lastPageLabel = translation.lastPage;

      this.getRangeLabel = (page, pageSize, length) => {
        if (length === 0 || pageSize === 0) {
          return `0 ${translation.of} ${length}`;
        }
        length = Math.max(length, 0);
        const startIndex = page * pageSize;
        const endIndex =
          startIndex < length ? Math.min(startIndex + pageSize, length) : startIndex + pageSize;
        return `${startIndex + 1} - ${endIndex} ${translation.of} ${length}`;
      };

      // This is required to update the paginator labels after the translation is loaded
      this.changes.next();
    });
  }
}
```

In this code, `TranslocoPaginatorIntl` is a custom `MatPaginatorIntl` that uses `Transloco` for translations. It subscribes to the translations for the `'table'` key and updates the labels accordingly.

Then, you need to provide `TranslocoPaginatorIntl` in your module:

```
import { MatPaginatorIntl } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { TranslocoModule, TranslocoService } from '@ngneat/transloco';
import { TranslocoPaginatorIntl } from './your/path/to/transloco-paginator-intl';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // ... other modules
    TranslocoModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    // ... other providers
    {
      provide: MatPaginatorIntl,
      useClass: TranslocoPaginatorIntl,
      deps: [TranslocoService],
    },
  ],
  // ... other properties
})
export class YourModule {}
```

In this code,

```
{
  provide: MatPaginatorIntl,
  useClass: TranslocoPaginatorIntl,
  deps: [TranslocoService],
},
```

tells Angular to use `TranslocoPaginatorIntl` instead of the default `MatPaginatorIntl`.

**NOTE:**

Remember to replace `'table'` with the actual key in your translation files, and replace the translation keys (`itemsPerPage`, `nextPage`, etc.) with the actual keys in your translation files. My i18n setup is for en-us & zh-tw. The i18n json files sample are as follows:

en-us.json

```
{
  "table": {
    "search": "Search",
    "keywords": "Keywords",
    "itemsPerPage": "Items per page",
    "nextPage": "Next page",
    "previousPage": "Previous page",
    "firstPage": "First page",
    "lastPage": "Last page",
    "of": "of",
    "noData": "No data",
  }
}
```

zh-tw.json:

```
{
  "table": {
    "search": "搜尋",
    "keywords": "關鍵字",
    "itemsPerPage": "每頁數量",
    "nextPage": "下一頁",
    "previousPage": "上一頁",
    "firstPage": "第一頁",
    "lastPage": "最後一頁",
    "of": "從",
    "noData": "沒有資料",
  }
}
```